# How to vectorize the intersection of each row and a list and find those that has a non-empty one?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I have a large dataset and when I run it it takes very longtime.
Generally speaking I find that the only way to avoid it we have to vectorize it using numpy. Or I maybe be wrong and you may have another solution. I simplifiy the problem in terms of dataset as below. Please let me know if you have a nice an elegant solution?

```
dfData = pd.DataFrame({'id':[112,14,45,34,78], 'x1':[4,6,1,2,9], 'x2':[1,2,3,4,5], 'x3':[9,3,4,1,2] })
ss = [2,3]
print(dfData)

result = []
ss_set = set(ss)

for i, row in dfData.iterrows():
    ll = row.drop('id').tolist()
    s_set = set(ll)
    if(len(ss_set.intersection(s_set)) > 0):
        result.append(row['id'])
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be faster. If not, at the very least, it is shorter:

```
ts = sum([(dfData.set_index('id') == s) for s in ss]).sum(axis=1)>0
ts[ts].index.values
```

produces

```
array([14, 45, 34, 78], dtype=int64)
```

to unpick this (I do recommend you execute different bits of this separately to understand what happens),

1. `(dfData.set_index('id') == s)` returns a df of the same shape as `dfData` where each element is True or False depending on whether it is equal to s or not
2. `[(dfData.set_index('id') == s) for s in ss]` creates a list of such dfs for each value of `s` in `ss=[2,3]]`
3. `sum(...)` adds them all up element by element (True is counted is 1 and False as 0, naturally)
4. after step 3, if any element is >0 then that element in df is either a 2 or a 3 (for our example)
5. `(...).sum(axis=1)` sums up these vlaues by row. If any row value is >0 then there is a match in that row
6. Finally `ts` is a time series with True/False, where True corresponds to the row that has a match
7. `ts[ts].index.values` just pulls out the `id`s that correspond to True (matches)